# How does the 'limit' parameter to the 'cropdetect' filter work in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, crop

I have a number of videos that have a (nominally) black border... and I'd like to have the black border cropped off.

I've used 'ffmpeg' a lot for various manipulations of videos... and I was hoping I'd be able to use the tool again to automatically do this cropping... and hence, I found out about the 'cropdetect' filter -- see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect.

While I can use it to determine 'almost correct' crop values, I can't get the filter to work properly, probably because I can't understand what the documentation is trying to describe about the 'limit' parameter, viz:-

```
limit: Set higher black value threshold, which can be optionally
specified from nothing (0) to everything (255 for 8-bit based
formats). An intensity value greater to the set value is considered
non-black. It defaults to 24. You can also specify a value between 0.0
and 1.0 which will be scaled depending on the bitdepth of the pixel
format.
```

I can determine what the RGB/HSV/HSL values are for the background black colour... but how is the 'limit' parameter used?  How does its value affect how 'close' the cropping is done?

As a secondary question, if I specify the limit value as '255', I get negative values in the 'crop=W:H:x:y' outputs.  Is this a problem... or I'm simply misunderstanding what it's trying to tell me...?

Using ffmpeg N-94396-g47b6ca0b02 under Windows 8 32-bit.

I'd appreciate any pointers...   Thanks!

Comment: I'm also seeing negative `w` and `h` values sometimes logged by cropdetect and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The cropdetect checks the first component of each frame (luma for YUV pixel format inputs; for RGB, it is usually the R plane, but depends on which is stored first)

The limit is the threshold value. So if limit is 24 and the pixel's value for the first component is 25, then that is considered a non-black pixel and hence part of the content.

A limit of 0 would mean consider all values as content, then why run the filter. Similarly, 255 for an 8-bit input would mean consider all values as black. Again, why run the filter? A valid range for limit in absolute pixel values is [1-254] for 8-bit content. Alternatively, you can also specify (0-1) for a normalized value i.e. a value of 0.4 for 8-bit input would be translated to 0.4*256 - 1 = 101.4 = 101.